# how to open grib file in r software

Tags: r, grib

In r, I've been accessing netcdf files and just wish to check the equivalent data which is provided also within a grib file (i.e. ERA5 data) - what is the best means to do so?

Thanks
Trisha

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501257/how-to-convert-grib1-to-netcdf-using-r